# Proving a function is positive

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let
$$
f(x) = 2\sqrt{1+x} + x\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}-2(1+x) \quad \text{for} \quad x \geq 0.
$$
I need to prove that $f(x) \geq 0$. (At least, I think this is true from plotting the function. At the very least I require a good lower bound for the function.)

What I have found so far is that 
$$
f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = 0,
$$
$$
f'''(0) = \frac{9}{16},
$$
$$
f(x) \sim \frac{x^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2}} \quad \text{as} \quad x\rightarrow\infty
$$
$$
f'''(x) \sim -\frac{3}{8\sqrt{2}x^{3/2}} \quad \text{as} \quad x\rightarrow\infty.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $t= \sqrt{x+1}\geq 1$, so $x=t^2-1$ and

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) &=& 2t(1-t)-(1-t)(1+t)\sqrt{{t^2+1\over 2}}\\
&=& (1-t)\Big(2t-(1+t)\sqrt{t^2+1\over 2} \Big)
\end{eqnarray}

Since $1-t\leq 0$ we have to prove $$2t\leq (1+t)\sqrt{t^2+1\over 2}$$

or $$ 8t^2\leq (t+1)^2(t^2+1)$$ and this should be easy to prove... since it is equivalent to
$$ 0\leq (t-1)^2(t^2+4t+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x\geq 6$, then $2\sqrt(1+x)\geq 2$, and $x\sqrt(1+\frac{x}{2}) \geq 2x$. So the inequality follows. For $0\leq x\leq 6$, you may consider $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that
$$2\left(\sqrt{1+x}-1\right)+x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}-2\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}+\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}-2\geq0$$ or
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}-\frac{2\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}\geq0$$
$$\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)(1+x)}+\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}-2\sqrt{1+x}\geq0$$ or
$$\sqrt{1+x}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}-1\right)+\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}-\sqrt{1+x}\geq0$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}+\sqrt{1+x}}\geq0$$ or
$$\sqrt{(1+x)\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)}+x\geq\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}},$$ which is obvious.